# PHP send email GMAIL error

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email using php.

```
public function email($to, $title, $message){
        $from = "me@mysite.com";
        $headers = "From: {$from}\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: {$from}\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$from}\r\n";

        $headers .= "Organization: InfiniSys, inc.\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";


        $subject = $title;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

The message sends;however, gmail give me an error.
"Gmail could not verify that mysite.com actually sent this message (and not a spammer)".

SPF record:(i have no idea what this is)

```
SPF record lookup and validation for: rrh.com

SPF records are published in DNS as TXT records.

The TXT records found for your domain are:
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a:mailman1-eqix-sjo.packet8.net a:mailman1-eq.packet8.net -all 
google-site-verification=GDHGdTnww1rIsh46Zd-n7I-E6d6Fa1n83XZ0ppfx4e8 
MS=ms49526710 
google-site-verification=-O2gI7Ji-rmEFlZQq8d85jHef7bEk0UcDXt-6MW419I 

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record. 

Found v=spf1 record for rrh.com: 
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a:mailman1-eqix-sjo.packet8.net a:mailman1-eq.packet8.net -all 

evaluating...
SPF record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF librar
```

Comment: Its eiter a header issue or a misconfiguration on my end. I always google before i post for help.

Comment: What does your SPF record look like?

Comment: use phpmailer instead https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @Chris i updated my question

Comment: I don't see a web server in there at all. Have you tried adding it as an authorized sender?

Comment: An SPF record is added to your DNS. Check your hosting companies help pages. But it says that it past SPF check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to your code. If you are sending mail as `me@mysite.com`, you need to have sending server IP hostname in SPF record for `mysite.com` domain to tell Gmail and other mailservers, that your server is permitted to send mails for `mysite.com` domain.

So, you should update your current DNS record:
`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a:mailman1-eqix-sjo.packet8.net a:mailman1-eq.packet8.net -all`
to include your server hostname:
`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a:mailman1-eqix-sjo.packet8.net a:mailman1-eq.packet8.net a:my.server.hostname -all`

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this is EXACTLY what i was looking for, let me update my settings right neow